# How to disable Rails 5 "X-Request-Id" header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

On Rails 5, all requests includes an unique identifier accessible on application and displayed on HTTP response headers, called "X-Request-Id".

This identifier is very useful for debugging and logging, but I'm having trouble with this in a very old web client.

I tried to clear the header but it did not work.

```
response.headers['X-Request-Id'] = nil
```

How can I remove this information from headers?

Comment: Hugo, did my solution worked for you? Do you need more information?

Answer (score 5):

You can disable it by adding this line in your **config/application.rb** file:

```ruby
config.middleware.delete ActionDispatch::RequestId
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, in alignment with official documentation: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-middleware

Answer (score 0):

You can disable this header information, setting by nil this request attribute.

```
request.request_id = nil
```